# getting the child tag based on parent tag from xml

Tags: android, xml

guys i have the following xml

```
<Point scount ="1">
  <Image name="app.png" />
</Point>
```

I need to parse the xml like this First i need to goto that `<Point>` and then in that i need to  pick the `<image>` tag.

how to do that, now i am fetching the value from image tag like this.

```
NodeList image = doc.getElementsByTagName("Image");
String imagess = ((Element)image.item(imageindex)).getAttribute("name");
```

how to acheive this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this

```
NodeList image = doc.getElementsByTagName("Point");
    Node singleTerminalNode = image.item(i);
            Element firstLevel = (Element)singleTerminalNode;
            NodeList value1Nodes = (firstLevel).getElementsByTagName("Image");
            imagess = ((Element)value1Nodes.item(imageindex)).getAttribute("name");
```