# Parse xml data in android

Tags: android, xml, parsing

I want to parse the below data in android.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

 Info: POST /Remindz_api/user/loginHTTP/1.1 
 Host: www.narola.co 
 Accept: www.narola.co.beepz.api+xml 
 HTTP 1.1 200 OK 
 Content-Type: www.narola.co.beepz.api+xml; 
 Allow : GET,POST

  <user id="43">
    <firstname>Dfdf</firstname>
    <lasttname>p2</lasttname>
    <email>p</email>
    <telephone>2236</telephone>
    <created_on>2013-01-04 04:38:05</created_on>
    <atom:link <a href="http://www.narola.co/remindz/reminders/43"></a> />
  </user>
```

I had used below code but due to the data is purely xml i cant parse it.

```
DocumentBuilder newDocumentBuilder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
Document parse = newDocumentBuilder.parse(new ByteArrayInputStream(result.getBytes()));
Log.d("result",parse.getChildNodes().toString());
```

Thanks In advace.

Comment: Just go through this and make it on your own.. http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-xml-parsing-tutorial/

Comment: I can't parse string using this because my parent tag is <user id="13"> So what can make my parent tag.

Comment: then try this one.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9272607/getting-the-child-tag-based-on-parent-tag-from-xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you must extract the correct XML from the chunk of text you received.

This lies down to two manipulations:

- Stripping off all the HTTP-related lines
- Modify the `<atom:link\>` syntax, which is invalid according to XML rules, to something like this:

This task can be carried out by previously processing the raw text with regular expressions. In your case these expressions could be used.

```
public class XMLTest {

    static String data = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n" + "\n" + " Info: POST /Remindz_api/user/loginHTTP/1.1\n"
            + " Host: www.narola.co \n" + " Accept: www.narola.co.beepz.api+xml\n" + " HTTP 1.1 200 OK \n"
            + " Content-Type: www.narola.co.beepz.api+xml;\n" + " Allow : GET,POST\n" + "\n" + "  <user id=\"43\">\n"
            + "    <firstname>Dfdf</firstname>\n" + "    <lasttname>p2</lasttname>\n" + "    <email>p</email>\n"
            + "    <telephone>2236</telephone>\n" + "    <created_on>2013-01-04 04:38:05</created_on>\n"
            + "    <atom:link <a href=\"http://www.narola.co/remindz/reminders/43\"></a> />\n" + "  </user>";

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        /*
         * This strips off "Param:Value"-style lines 
         */
        String xmlData = data.replaceAll(" *[a-z\\-A-Z]* *:[^<]*\n", "");
        /*
         * This strips off "HTTP line" 
         */
        xmlData = xmlData.replaceAll(" *HTTP .*\n", "");

        /*
         * Correct atom:link format
         */
        xmlData = xmlData.replaceAll("<atom:link (.*) />", "<atom:link>$1</atom:link>"); 

        try {
            DocumentBuilder newDocumentBuilder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();

            Document doc = newDocumentBuilder.parse(new ByteArrayInputStream(xmlData.getBytes("UTF-8")));

            Element elem = doc.getDocumentElement();
            dump("", elem);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void dump(final String pad, final Node node)
    {
        System.out.println(pad + node.toString());

        if(node.getChildNodes() != null)
        {
            for(int i=0; i< node.getChildNodes().getLength();i++)
            {
                dump(pad + " ", node.getChildNodes().item(i));
            }
        }
    }
```

Resulting text is a prefect valid XML that can no be fed into DOM parser:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

  <user id="43">
    <firstname>Dfdf</firstname>
    <lasttname>p2</lasttname>
    <email>p</email>
    <telephone>2236</telephone>
    <created_on>2013-01-04 04:38:05</created_on>
    <atom:link><a href="http://www.narola.co/remindz/reminders/43"></a></atom:link>
  </user>
```

Comment: It does work. Have you tried executing XMLTest? The produced XML is a valid XML. The parser could be a little bit picky about the spaces between the root element and the xml declaration. What does not exactly work? Dump a stacktrace of the error

Comment: I upated the code so the XML is effectively processed and it is correct. All elements are dumped.

Comment: @Fermando neither you are wrong nor me. Pls take my data as whole then apply your statement its not working. It will only work on your string(Develpoed by you with lots of joining.) I dont why its not working.

Answer (score 0):

Use xml parsing techniques such as `XmlPullParser` ,`SAX parser` or `DOM parser`.

XML Pull parser is the parser recommended in the developer's site of android [Here](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidXML/article.html) is a tutorial for Pull parser .